# ActionMode background not working on lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

Am trying to change the background color of the contextual action bar.
I did it in the following manner

v21/themes.xml & themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Widget.ActionMode</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/Widget.ActionMode</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="Widget.ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="background">@color/highlight_green</item>
</style>
```

The background color works fine in pre-lollipop devices. But does not work in lollipop.

Note: Tried adding

```
<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/highlight_green</item>
<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/highlight_green</item>
```

as well. But did not work.

Comment: have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem since last library update, and adding the "actionModeBackground" item in my theme solved it.

Are you sure you are adding it under MyTheme, and not under Widget.ActionMode ?

Comment: Yes i added it under MyTheme and not under Widget.ActionMode.

Answer (score 0):

Try only the next code:

**Styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionMode</item>
</style>



<style name="ActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@color/color_bar</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/color_bar</item>
</style>
```